# FunctionInvocationException when Azure function is called

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-functions, production

I'm having an issue with my Azure function. The function cannot startup because a FunctionInvocationException is being thrown each time.

The inner exception being an InvalidOperationException with the below message:

> PartitionKey must be supplied for this operation

I have two bindings in my function that connect to a Document DB, one is an in binding that retrieves a specific document from a collection, and the other is an out binding used for auditing.

These both work fine in my dev, qa, and uat environments it is only the production environment that is having an issue. Both collections (for the settings and the auditing) were created without a partition key, the same as every environment.

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>          at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient+d__347.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)

Any ideas?

I've tried deleting and remaking the audit collection but that didn't work. I don't get why the other environments are fine, but this one isn't.

Edit:

The function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\Cso.Notification.Function.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Cso.Notification.Function.Program.Run",
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "webHookType": "genericJson",
      "name": "request",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "subscriberSettings",
      "databaseName": "CSO",
      "collectionName": "Settings",
      "id": "SubscriberSettings",
      "connection": "CsoDocDb",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "collector",
      "databaseName": "CSO",
      "collectionName": "AuditJSON",
      "connection": "CsoDocDb",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please show your code/bindings

Comment: Can you share Invocation Id, Timestamp and region of your app? Would try and look through logs to see if i can find something specific.

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Are all of your environments running in Azure, or are some running on a dev machine? 2. What happens if you try to use `DocumentClient` directly to perform a similar operation on that collection -- does it give you the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer. One of the documents we were querying for an initial value (SubscriberSettings) was incorrectly setup with a PartitionKey.

Deleting the collection and remaking it without a partition key did the trick.